# Android - Ion FutureCallBack with result=""

Tags: android, android-ion

I am developing an App and I use the lib Ion from koush: [here](https://github.com/koush/ion)

Sometimes it works great and I get the result "succeed" or "User already exists" from the php file(echo "succeed";) and sometimes the result is "" an empty string.

I cant post the whole code because it is too much but you can ask for parts of it.
Is there someone who is familiar with Ion and could help me?

```
public void registerNewUser(String fname, String lname, String email,
        String country, String aboutu, String uidenty, final Runnable r) {
    Ion.with(context,
            "http://project.com/index.php")
            .setBodyParameter("firstname", fname)
            .setBodyParameter("lastname", lname)
            .setBodyParameter("email", email)
            .setBodyParameter("country", country)
            .setBodyParameter("aboutu", aboutu)
            .setBodyParameter("useridentification", uidenty)
            .setBodyParameter("tag", "register").asString()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception ex, String res) {
                    if (ex != null) {
                        Log.e("ion-error", ex.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(
                                context,
                                "The registration failed. Try again later.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if ("succeed".equals(res.replace("\t", " ")
                            .trim())) {
                        r.run();
                    } else if ("User already exists".equals(res.replace(
                            "\t", " ").trim())) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                context,
                                "This Email is already in use. Try another one.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Maybe check your server logs when that happens. Also enable verbose logging in ion and provide that as well.

Comment: I found out that it only happens when debugging. Do not set the breakpoint in the FutureCallBack.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any exception while debugging?
Try to set Timeout value.

```
Ion.with(context,
        "http://project.com/index.php")
        .setBodyParameter("firstname", fname)
        .setBodyParameter("lastname", lname)
        .setBodyParameter("email", email)
        .setBodyParameter("country", country)
        .setBodyParameter("aboutu", aboutu)
        .setBodyParameter("useridentification", uidenty)
        .setBodyParameter("tag", "register")
        .asString()
        .setTimeout(20000)
        .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
         ........................your code.......
         }
```